# Does \Twoheadleftrightarrow exist? How to write my own?

Tags: macros, arrows

I'm a LaTeX newbie.
I am writing a document in which I need to have a two-headed bidirectional arrow.
Two-headed like `\twoheadleftarrow`, bidirectional like `\leftrightarrow`.

Is there any package that offers something like this?
If not, how do I "roll my own"?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\twoheadleftarrow` and `\twoheadrightarrow` can be combined to `\twoheadleftrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\twoheadleftrightarrow}{%
  \twoheadleftarrow
  \mathrel{\mkern-15mu}%
  \twoheadrightarrow
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \twoheadleftrightarrow
  \scriptstyle \twoheadleftrightarrow
  \scriptscriptstyle \twoheadleftrightarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The symbols can also be combined using `\joinrel`, which is some negative space that should counteract the side bearings. However, I could see a small gap in `\scriptscriptstyle` with class option `10pt`, thus I have removed another `-0.5mu`. And the new `\longtwoheadleftrightarrow` has an optional argument, which allows further adjustment if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\longtwoheadleftrightarrow}[1][.5]{%
  \twoheadleftarrow
  \joinrel
  \mathrel{\mkern-#1mu}%
  \twoheadrightarrow
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \longtwoheadleftrightarrow
  \scriptstyle \longtwoheadleftrightarrow
  \scriptscriptstyle \longtwoheadleftrightarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \longtwoheadleftrightarrow]

An even longer version can be composed with `\relbar` in the middle.

Also an expandable version can be constructed similar to `\xrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\xtwoheadleftrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 99{10}{10}\twoheadleftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\twoheadleftrightarrowfill@}{%
  \arrowfill@\twoheadleftarrow\relbar\twoheadrightarrow
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \xtwoheadleftrightarrow[\text{under}]{\text{over}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \xtwoheadleftrightarrow]

Comment: While we are at it - how would one go making them longer?

I guess one would do the same kind of "composition" adding a dash-like symbol in the middle.

Comment: @tobiatesan Look into Herbert Voß's “Math Mode” (`texdoc mathmode`); in section 38 it is explained how to define `\xleftrightarrow` and it should suffice to adapt the definition in order to use the double head arrows.

Comment: The strange behavior of `\joinrel` is also visible when you try `\longrightarrow` in scriptscript style: see http://i.stack.imgur.com/wgVZb.png

Comment: @egreg: `\joinrel` assumes that `1.5mu` is equal or larger than the symbol's side bearing, but the amount of the side bearings depend on the font and might not follow and scale with a specific `mu` value.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I know; I was just surprised that this happened with CM fonts, when I discovered it some time ago. I guess that Knuth has never used `\longrightarrow` in scriptscript style, which I'm not really surprised of. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Because of the round line ends, small dents in the middle of the horizontal line of `\longrightarrow` are even visible for normal size. But AFAIK it is too late for bug reports (`\joinrel`/`\longrightarrow` of `plain.tex`). Now it's a feature that these bugs are preserved and fixed do not change existing documents.